# Is there a good Netbeans plugin for R?

Tags: netbeans, r

I am looking for a good Netbeans plugin for R. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Purushotham: http://www.r-project.org/

Comment: Why do you use Netbeans? Try Eclipse and StatET plugin. http://www.walware.de/goto/statet

Comment: I think that the answer is "no".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any way to make it work seemlessly.  As a Netbeans user, I understand how convenient such a plugin would be.  The closest that you can get is probably R-Java, but that isn't right for most applications.