# Is there any plugin for R in Netbeans?

Tags: c++, r, netbeans

I am working on one project in which i need to code in R and C++. I found following post to be very useful for calling R in C++.

[Calling R Function from C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457635/calling-r-function-from-c)

In order to make it organized, i m using Netbeans IDE but i cannot code R in netbeans. Is there any plugin in netbeans so that i can call R function from C++ program in the same project.

Regards

Comment: Two years ago the answer was no: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3147902/602276. I doubt that it has changed since then.

Comment: To facilitate interfacing C++ code in R package try using Rcpp package, for more details see http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html

Comment: As @java_xof said, You should look at `Rcpp`. And since you said "I am working on one project in which i need to code in R and C++" you could consider using [RStudio](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/download/desktop)  which [has recently added](http://blog.rstudio.org/2012/11/29/rstudio-and-rcpp/) C++ support of some kind (and supports R obviously).

Comment: I need to use in Netbeans as i have other dependency too.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue these days, and cannot find better than this workaround:

1. Install Eclipse, and [CDT plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) for C/C++, and [StatET plugin](http://www.walware.de/goto/statet) for R.
2. Inside your main folder, create a C/C++ project - let's say 'mypackage_Cpp' - where the C/C++ sources are (usually src/), *and then* a R project - let's say 'mypackage_R' - where you have the R files (usually R/ folder). Tick the box "reference mypackage_Cpp".

Then C/C++ code navigation/formatting and refactoring options (99% of what I use) are functional. In addition you can use the StatET features (some refactoring, objects browser, run R code...).

RStudio is nice for R but lack the above quoted features (format/refactor/navigate) for C/C++. Finally I would prefer a netbeans solution, but have no time to write a module now.

Note: [devtools](http://www.rstudio.com/projects/devtools/) also seems interesting, probably achieving in a cleaner way what I attempted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13979405/r-package-use-a-custom-file-directories-structure-in-pkg-r-and-pkg-src-folders).